# Issue with Yazeed44 MultiImagePicker

Tags: android

I am using 'net.yazeed44.imagepicker:imagepicker:1.1.6', and it works, but when I try to take a picture with it, the image shows as empty. I also include     maven {url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"} in my repository

This is how I handle the listener

```
 public void onPickedSuccessfully(final ArrayList<ImageEntry> images) {
        imageLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_layout);
        imageScroll = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_scroll);
        imageLayout.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        for(ImageEntry image : images){
            if (imageCount < 5) {
                imageCount++;
                imageScroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                View view = viewBuilder.createThumbnail(getActivity(), image.path);
                thumbnails.add(view);
                thumbnailsPaths.add(image.path);
                view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
                imageLayout.addView(view);
                MainActivity.imageArray.add(image.path);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reached 5 photo limit", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I handle creating the thumbnail

```
    public View createThumbnail(Activity activity, String imagePath) {
    ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    Bitmap image = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), 100, 100);
    lp.setMargins(15,0,15,0);
    view.setLayoutParams(lp);
    view.setImageBitmap(image);
    return view;
    }
```

Could it be that the picture I take does not return a image path? If nothing else please point me to a trust worthy image picker please, thanks a lot

Comment: Add some log to determine where the error is

Comment: @kaitian521 There is no errors its just when I take a photo from the camera nothing appears